# Ansible managed k3s deployment fails due to "Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found." error

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, k3s

I'm having a k3s (single node) kubernetes cluster and try to make a deployment on it via ansible.
I know of cource that I use a k8s collection for k3s, but maybe it can be solved anyhow.

The relevant part of my playbook is:

```
---
- hosts: k3s_cluster
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Create a Deployment by reading the definition from a local file
    kubernetes.core.k8s:
      api_key: mytoken
      state: present
      src: deployment.yml
```

The deployment file is simple.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

If I do it directly via kubectl it works.
The config exists on the target host(and also on my local machine) in ~/.kube/config. Specifying that location doesn't help.

Comment: It would be good if you could write how Ansible is installed? As a pod in k3s cluster or separately / independently from k3s?

Comment: Maybe user that ansible uses to connect to k3s_cluster host is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was (as the error message inidcated) the kubeconfig location. I was using https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s-ansible to deploy kubernetes k3s.

The Problem: As Sysadmin mentioned in his post, k3s puts the config into /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml. But the used ansible collection(https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_module.html) expects it to be ins /home/user/.kube/config.

Solution: Either follow Sysadmin suggestions and set the global variable. But then you still have to amend the user rights for the file. Or copy /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml to /home/user/.kube/config (also renaming it to config and setting user rights in the process).

Answer (score 0):

Provide the `host` to access the API server. If not using a tls cert chain that can be validated by your system certificates you may also need `validate_certs`  set to false.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ansible+k3s on Raspberry Pi CM4 cluster

1. **Here is a video tutorial**

[How to install k3s on Raspberry Pi CM4 cluster using Ansible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAl4P6tii7M)

##### Requirements:

###### For Raspberry Pi / CM4

```
cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory
```

added to

```
/boot/cmdline.txt
```

###### For Ansible

- ansible user added to each remote node
- ansible user added to sudo/wheel/admins group
- sudo/wheel/admins group set in /etc/sudoers to perform command with elevated privileges

1. Create ansible inventory

```bash
sudo vim /etc/ansible/hosts
```

```yaml
all:
  children:
    master:
      hosts:
        master-node:
          ansible_host: 10.10.0.112
          ansible_user: ansible
    workers:
      hosts:
        worker-node-1:
          ansible_host: 10.10.0.102
          ansible_user: ansible
        worker-node-2:
          ansible_host: 10.10.0.104
          ansible_user: ansible
```

2. Create ansible playbook. See the video for the explanation.

```bash
vim k3s-raspberry-cluster.yml
```

3. Put the below content into this file.

```yaml
---
- name: Install K3s on Master Node
  hosts: master
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install K3s
      shell: curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--disable traefik,servicelb" K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE="644" sh -

    - name: Install NGINX as ingress controller
      shell: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
    - name: Create a patch file for NGINX ingress controller 
      shell:
        cmd: |
          cat > ingress.yaml << EOF
            spec:
              template:
                spec:
                  hostNetwork: true
          EOF
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash

    - name: patch NGINX ingress controller
      shell: kubectl patch deployment ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx --patch "$(cat ingress.yaml)"

    - name: Get K3s node token
      shell: cat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/node-token
      register: k3s_token
      delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"



- name: Install K3s on Worker Nodes
  hosts: workers
  become: yes
  vars:
    k3s_url: "https://{{ hostvars['master-node']['ansible_host'] }}:6443"
    k3s_token: "{{ hostvars['master-node'].k3s_token.stdout }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Join worker nodes to the cluster
      shell: "curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_URL={{ k3s_url }} K3S_TOKEN={{ k3s_token }} sh -"


- name: Label K3s workers on Master Node
  hosts: master
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Label worker 1
      shell: kubectl label nodes worker1 kubernetes.io/role=worker
    - name: Label worker 2
      shell: kubectl label nodes worker2 kubernetes.io/role=worker
```

4. Run the playbook like below:

```bash
ansible-playbook k3s-raspberry-cluster.yml
```

5. Check on the remote k3s master node the configuration using below commands:

```bash
kubectl get nodes
kubectl get pods -A
kubectl get svc -A
kubectl get all -A
```

Scripts and configuration files are available [here:](https://github.com/sysadmin-info/ansible)

##### Add k3s configuration into the environment if needed on master node after the deployment what usually is not needed.

Edit the file

```bash
sudo vim /etc/environment
```

Add the below entry:

```
KUBECONFIG=/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
```

```bash
source /etc/environment
```

Explanation:
source is a Bash shell built-in command that executes the content of the file passed as an argument in the current shell. It has a synonym in . (period).